# can not execute click() properly

Tags: selenium, click, python-3.7

im using python 3.7.4, latest selenium and geckodriver, and Firefox version 69.0.1.

im trying to simply use click() on the 'im feeling lucky' button at google homepage, but i get the error
`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view`.

i tried using `msg_box.location_once_scrolled_into_view` and get_element_by_class/id/name to no avail. this is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = 'https://www.google.com'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(4)
msg_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('RNmpXc')
msg_box.location_once_scrolled_into_view
time.sleep(1)
msg_box.click()
```

what could cause the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Induce `WebDriverWait` and  `presence_of_element_located`()

Induce `javascript executor`.However webdriver click on button isn't working.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.google.com'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
element=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'RNmpXc')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element) worked. although can you explain how its different than element.click()?

Comment: I have mentioned that in post webdriver click Isn’t working

Comment: If you provide some text in search box then webdriver click would work

Comment: i don't know, i have some other test code where i use x.click() where x is some element, and it does function correctly. that's why im confused as to why it did not work with the 'im feeling lucky' button
EDIT: ahh skipped your latest post. it might be the cause actually. ill check it later for myself. anyways thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

The message

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  could not be scrolled into view.

means that the  is not selectable at the moment. Your program is trying to interact with it but it cannot be scrolled into view. It could be e.g. that the programm is trying to find the element but then it (example) "disappears" (for example pop up or a new button appears) and hence it cannot be scrolled into view and hence it is not clickable.

You can add the wait condition (when a pop-up appears) it waits for couple of seconds after popup disappears it is clicking on the element.

*msgBox02 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "EXAMPLE")))
msgBox02.click()*

NOTE: I added example same as RNmpXc

Comment: <input class="RNmpXc" value="I'm Feeling Lucky" aria-label="I'm Feeling Lucky" name="btnI" type="submit" jsaction="sf.lck" data-ved="0ahUKEwiC-qan-ILlAhVhmeAKHUTxBgkQ19QECAk"> where did you see ID in this DOM?

Comment: @stacktome regarding ID it is just an example in this case. Here By.CLASS_NAME was used. When selecting xpath/css selectors/ID the procedure should be the same